# Google Analytics for ios with Pod

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am using CocoaPods for integrate Google Analytics in iOS .
I referred this link
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?configured=true

My code is .

```
 NSError *configureError;

[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];

 NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);
```

My Log is :

> Attempted to configure [Identity, Analytics, AdMob, SignIn, AppInvite, CloudMessaging].
>
> Successfully configured [].
>
> Failed to configure [].
>
> Subspecs not present, so not configured [Identity, Analytics, AdMob, SignIn, AppInvite, CloudMessaging].

Comment: Could you enter the podfile entry you have used?

Comment: facing same error, have you figure out?